# R - gsub issues when writing csv

Tags: r, csv, character-encoding, gsub

I am trying to gsub() the code below:

"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tThird tier -  England\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

So far I have used

```
Player_data$Player_League_Level = gsub('\n','',gsub('\t','',gsub('\r','',Player_data$Player_League_Level)))
```

Which produces:   "Third tier -  England"

However when I write the data.frame into a csv. The data produced looks like this in Excel:

Third tierÂ -Â Â England

How do I remove the 'Â' for when I write the data.frame into a csv.

Comment: Have you tried opening it up in a text editor instead of excel? This could be an excel issue and not with how you're writing your csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters in your string "Third tierÂ -Â Â England" looks like Non-ASCII characters. In this case, you could remove Non-ASCII characters, as below:

```
iconv("Third tierÂ -Â Â England", "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")
#[1] "Third tier -  England"
```